# pip is visible in system (C disk) but not for user

Tags: python, cmd, module, pip, path

I installed pip and it is visible from C: disk. Command     `C:\>pip -v` shows version, etc.

But if I get error if I try to reach pip from one directory deeper (C:\Users):

```
C:\Users>pip -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

My environment variables (some of them):

[image: environment variables]

Overall I want to be able to use pip in VS Code for packages installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by running this command:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

It ensured that python and its packages (therefore also pip) is included in PATH.

Now `C:\Users>pip -v` also works!